# Installation free space

Tags: software-installation, disk-usage

I'm trying to download some software (Unity game engine 2017.3). As part of the installation process, I downloaded the installation assistant, but when I try to download the actual package, the assistant says that I'm short on space, by about 50MB. When I close and reopen the assistant, the free space figure can change, even if I haven't done anything. I've tried removing useless applications and deleting old files, but that seems to have no effect on the free space figure. I've posted this question on the Unity forums as well (the game engine, not the interface). I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.04 if it helps.

Comment: Does it report what filesystem that is short of space ? And can you update your question with the output of `df -h`?

Comment: No, I'm afraid it doesn't name the filesystem. Here's the output of the command:https://i.imgur.com/57S2Z6d.png

Comment: Your root filesystem ( / ) is very full, only 2.5 GB of 25 GB free. Try to look into /boot to see if there are many kernel files there (run `sudo apt autoremove` to remove unneeded file there and other not needed files. Also check /var/log for many / large files ...

Comment: Thanks. I've had a look in those directories, and there are quite a few files there that don't seem to serve a purpose. is there an index for the purposes the files perform?